# Using named arguments for functions

Tags: javascript, php, function

Is there any downside to using named arguments for functions in JavaScript and PHP. I don't see any downside. There's the fact that you need to extract them (though you don't absolutely have to I guess) - but you can use that as a way of using defaults. Eg.

**Javascript:**

```
function myFunction (opt)
{
    var name = opt.name || 'Barry',
        age  = opt.age  || 26,
        eyes = opt.eyes || 'brown';
}
```

And call it like this:

```
myFunction ({
    name: 'Fred',
    age: 56,
    eyes: 'pink'
})
```

**PHP**

```
function myFunction ($opt)
{
     $name = $opt['name'] ? $opt['name'] : 'Barry';
     $age  = $opt['age']  ? $opt['age']  : 26;
     $eyes = $opt['eyes'] ? $opt['eyes'] : 'brown';
}
```

EDIT: Maybe use the extract() function here to make things easier.

And call it like this:

```
myFunction ([
    'name' => 'Fred',
    'age'  => 56,
    'eyes' => 'pink'
])
```

Comment: In JavaScript you can unpack them efficiently with destructuring assignment and have defaults with default arguments.

Comment: You appear to be confusing "named arguments" with "an object".  You can pass any object you like to your functions.

Comment: @Richard In JS you assignig the `object` to the `opt` variable and in PHP the `array` to `$opt`, so you just passing the parameter `opt` (-; In other words - you do not understanding what you doing.

Comment: @neodan I know exactly what I'm doing - I'm trying to find out if there's any gotchas with this procedure.

Comment: @Richard the answer is NO, because it is a standard way to pass an array/object to a function (-;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript, you could use default values, like

```js
function myFunction({ name = 'Barry', age = 26, eyes = 'brown'} = {}) {
    console.log(name, age, eyes);
}

myFunction();
myFunction({ name: undefined, age: 30 });
myFunction({ name: 'jane', age: 35, eyes: 'blue' });
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any downside to using named arguments for functions in JavaScript and PHP

Just one. Neither PHP nor JavaScript support named arguments.

**EDIT**

Here [wiki page on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter) what named arguments really is, as many seem to get the concept wrong.

Comment: *"Neither PHP nor JavaScript support named arguments."* really?

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about an options object, not named arguments. Named arguments are not available in JavaScript, and would look something like this following line. Note that the parameters are not inside an object:

```
myFunction( name: 'Fred', age: 56, eyes: 'pink' );
```

Using an options object rather than individual function parameters is useful if there are more than a few arguments to pass. The object doesn't have to worry about ordering, or whether elements are optional.

ES2015 supports destructuring and defaults, which can simplify this even more, though the formatting may look very different at first...

```
function myFunction ({ name = 'Barry', age = 26, eyes = 'brown'})
{
    console.log(name, age, eyes);
}
```

This function will throw an error if an object is not passed, but it can accept an empty object, or one with any number of those keys. As Nina's answer shows, you would need *another* default to prevent that error:

```
function myFunction ({ name = 'Barry', age = 26, eyes = 'brown'} = {})
{
    console.log(name, age, eyes);
}
```